# controlling motor with PWM

Tags: motor, signal, pwm

I am using a [RCS-Model-M2313 R/C Servo](http://www.rcecho.com/RCS-Model-M2313-13g-RC-Metal-Gear-High-Torque-R-C-Hobby-Micro-Servo-SS840.html) and I have managed to create a PWM. My problem is that my motor doesn't react as I was expecting. I would like to control the motor angle with the duty cycle but it doesn't work. 
Indeed, with a 28% duty cycle, a 550 Hz frequency, 1.7V offset, a 3.3V signal from my MCU I can control it to come back to the same position. I have powered the servo with a 3.7 tension. 
When I change the duty cycle, the motor turn but doesn't stop anymore.

The datasheet doesn't give any information, I really need your advices. 
Thank you.
Regards,
Mattew

Comment: Personally, I advise testing with an oscilloscope if you haven't already. That way you can make sure you're getting an output of what you expect.

Comment: On the oscilloscope, the signal is perfect, I just cannot find the good parameters to control the angle

Comment: Please provide web references to motor data and anything else related and available.

Comment: http://www.rcecho.com/RCS-Model-M2313-13g-RC-Metal-Gear-High-Torque-R-C-Hobby-Micro-Servo-SS840.html

Comment: They don't give enough details (digital or analog ?, duty cycle ?).

Comment: Can you test this motor with some other hardware?

Comment: The duty cycle will control the speed not position. To control position, you'll need to measure it somehow and close a servo loop on speed/torque (PID) to that position.

Comment: @kenny - His "Motor" is actually a radio-control servo, which should have position feedback already built in.

Comment: For what it's worth, have you tried running the servo at 5V? I have never seen a servo specified to run at less then 4V (but then, I have not been looking at R/C equipment for a number of years).

Answer (score 3):

Your frequency is way too high, or conversely, you are not waiting long enough between pulses.  You should be sending a 1 to 2 ms pulse every 20 to 50 ms.  Note that this means 50 Hz maximum.

Also, your "1.7 V offset" makes no sense.  These pulses should generally be 0 to 5 V digital signals.  I followed the link you provided, but that only goes to a product sell page not a datasheet, so we can't tell exactly what voltage levels the digital signal must be.  When in doubt with hobby servo units, use 5 V logic.

Try a 1 ms pulse every 20 ms.  That should send the arm to one end.  Then try 2 ms every 20 ms.  That should send the arm to the other end.  Try it with the 3.3 V signal straight out of your processor and see if that works.  If it doesn't, make it a 0-5 V signal instead.  That really should work if everything else is hooked up right.  If you don't have a level translator chip, you can rig up something with a NPN transistor and pullup resistor.  That will invert, but just invert the processor output to compensate.  A HCT (note the T) logic gate powered at 5 V can also be used as a 3.3 V to 5 V converter.

Are you sure the processor power is properly filtered so that the current spikes the motor draws doesn't effect it?  A schematic and scope traces with a clear description of what happens in each case would help a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much, I cannot find a real datasheet, that's the main point. I have tried with my signal generator: 20Hz, it doesn't turn on the motor anymore. I cannot go bellow than 20% duty cycle. I am going to try with my MCU tomorrow I will keep you in touch.

Comment: @Mattew: This is not about duty cycle but about pulse width.  The servo mechanism is driven by the duration of the high-going pulses.  The length of the low level doesn't matter much as long as the pulses repeat every 20-50 ms or so.

Comment: I have bought a new motor, it works very well now, thank you !